# Option for disabling and enabling auto generated java classes using wsdl

Tags: java, websphere, rad

I am using RAD 9.1 and Websphere 8.5.

The webservice classes are already generated but whenever I manually edit the generated Java file, the server regenerates and my changes are lost.

I don't want this to happen; how can I switch off the regeneration of the Java classes when I modify them?

I didn't see this behaviour in my old version of RAD.

Comment: This is a service (not a client), correct? Did you have RAD generate from WSDL? Generate Java Bean Skeleton? JAX-WS or JAX-RPC?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Disable build automatically option in project menu (But be careful, if you do a clean or build, it will be regenerated again)
2. Try to have a parallel project, one with autogenerated things, and another copying your changes. Then, use the "copy" as a JAR file and associate to your main project.

Just temporary solutions, not so clean, but can do the job :P